# What is the command to remove all files and folders, on mac os x terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, rm

On Mac OS X terminal, how can we remove all files and folders, including hidden ones, recursively, except one directory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING:** running any command to recursively delete files is dangerous.  Always, always test before blindly running such dangerous commands, and **never** run them as the root user (or with sudo etc.), ever.

This is relatively easy to do with a bit of bash, you could even make it an argument you pass in if you are going to do this a lot.  But, for a once off, try something like my simple test below.

First, I will create some folders for testing:

```
cd test; mkdir -p one two three four five six .hidden
```

Then, I will create a bash script (in this case rm.bash) with the following content:

```
for i in `ls -A`
do      
        if [ ! "${i}" == 'three' ] && [ ! "${i}" == $0 ]; then 
                echo "would delete ${i}" 
        else    
                echo "not deleting ${i}" 
        fi
done
```

To explain: `ls -A` will print all files except the current folder and the parent (`.` and `..`).  We use this list with a `for` loop to iterate through all the contents.  I have decided (arbitrarily) that the only folder we will leave is "three" and that I don't want to delete the `rm.bash` script itself.

Hence, the `if` condition will only be true as long as the file/folder in question is not named either `three` or `rm.bash` (`$0` means this works no matter what you call the file).

Rather than running this immediately with `rm -rf ${i}` (which is dangerous), I have instead used a couple of `echo` commands to show what will be deleted and what will not.

Here was my sample output:

```
would delete five
would delete four
would delete one
not deleting rm.bash
would delete six
not deleting three
would delete two
```

Once you have verified that the script is taking the correct action, not deleting things that it should not etc., then you can change the code to this:

```
for i in `ls -A`
do      
        if [ ! "${i}" == 'three' ] && [ ! "${i}" == $0 ]; then 
                rm -rf ${i} 
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative. Same caveats apply as @Adam C's answer; don't run this without testing it.

Some demo data:

```
$ mkdir testing; cd testing
$ mkdir one two three four "fi ve"
$ touch one/one.txt two/two.txt three four/keep.txt fi\ ve/.hidden
```

Simulate deleting all but four/

```
$ find . -mindepth 1  -path ./four -prune -o -exec echo would remove "{}" +
```

Output:

```
would remove ./fi ve ./fi ve/.hidden ./two ./two/two.txt ./one ./one/one.txt ./three
```

Notes:

```
-mindepth 1  prevents including /.
Prune removes path four/ from processing, or...
-o means "or" (either prune the left, or exec on the right)
High speed / low resource use:
  find will stop processing a tree once pruned (no wasted operations)
  One xargs-style list is built (with +), removal happens in one command.
  To process one at a time, replace + with \;
Spaces are handled correctly within " "
-delete is shorter but may not operate on directories
find won't follow symlinks by default
```